# ArrayList.indexOf() is not recognizing Objects

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a `ParseObject` subclass , but everytime I want to get index of it it returns `0` so `mListSectionPos` returns an array of zero's (`hachCode` and `equals` methd implemented thanks to Apache Commons Utils).

It should be `String.valueOf(mListItems.indexOf(beer_section))`, but instead I'm using `mListSectionPos.add(mListItems.indexOf(current_item) - 1);` because it's working (more or less). Sometimes it cracks on `getCurrentSectionPosition()` that also works on `indexOf()` method.

So my question is: **why `indexOf()` always return `0` in this piece of code?**

It's based on https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/ListviewFilter - just adapted for ParseObject lists. Code below is my adaptation of his `MainActivity.java` that can be found [here](https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/ListviewFilter/blob/master/ListviewFilter/src/com/example/listviewfilter/ui/MainActivity.java):

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<PiwoSubclass>... params) {
        mListItems.clear();
        mListSectionPos.clear();
        ArrayList<PiwoSubclass> items = params[0];
        if(mItems != null) {
            if (mItems.size() > 0) {

                String prev_section = "";

                for (PiwoSubclass current_item : items) {
                    if (isCancelled()) break;
                    String current_section = current_item.getBeerName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());

                    if (!prev_section.equals(current_section)) {
                        PiwoSubclass beer_section = null;
                        beer_section = new PiwoSubclass();
                        beer_section.setBeerName(current_section);

                        Log.i("ASD-current", beer_section.getBeerName());

                        mListItems.add(beer_section);
                        mListItems.add(current_item);

                        // array list of section positions
                        mListSectionPos.add(mListItems.indexOf(current_item) - 1); // that want works although it's way around



                        // TODO why is that error?
                        Log.i("ASD-listSectionSize", String.valueOf(mListItems.indexOf(beer_section)));

                        prev_section = current_section;
                    } else {
                        mListItems.add(current_item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**PiwoSubclass**

```
public class PiwoSubclass extends ParseObject {

private String objectIdP;
private String marka;
private String marka_lowercase;

public PiwoSubclass() {
}

public String getObjectIdfromParse() {
    return this.getObjectId();
}

public String getMarka(){
    return this.getString("marka");
}

public String getBrewery(){
    return this.getString("brewery");
}

public String getBeerName(){
    return this.getString("beer_name");
}

public String getMarka_lowercase() {
    return this.getString("marka_lowercase");
}

public void setMarka(String value){
    put("marka", value);
}

public void setBeerName(String value){
    put("beer_name", value);
}

public void setMarka_lowercase(String value){
    put("marka_lowercase", value);
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31) // two randomly chosen prime numbers
            // if deriving: appendSuper(super.hashCode()).
            .append(getObjectIdfromParse())
            .toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //return super.equals(obj);
    if (!(obj instanceof PiwoSubclass))
        return false;
    if (obj == this)
        return true;

    marka_lowercase = getMarka_lowercase();
    PiwoSubclass rhs = (PiwoSubclass) obj;
    //Log.i("ASD-subclass", marka + "/" + rhs.getMarka());
    return new EqualsBuilder()
            // if deriving: appendSuper(super.equals(obj)).
            .append(marka_lowercase, rhs.getMarka_lowercase())
            .isEquals();
}
```

Now I have `IndexOutOfBounds` exception from `PinnedHeaderAdapter`:

```
public int getCurrentSectionPosition(int position) {
    //String listChar = mListItems.get(position).getBeerName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
    PiwoSubclass ps = mListItems.get(position); // TODO errorrrrrrrrr
    return mListItems.indexOf(ps);

}
```

Comment: indexOf returns an int, not an array

Comment: Yes, I know -  I meant`mListSectionPos` when called returns arrays of zeros. Updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Rami sure, updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you check for `mItems`

```
if(mItems != null) {
    if (mItems.size() > 0) {
```

but then you work with `items`

```
for (PiwoSubclass current_item : items) {
    /* ... */
}
```

and ignore `mItems` for the rest of the method. I don't see any connection between these two.

---

It seems `indexOf()` doesn't return 0 but 1, otherwise you would get an `ArrayList` full of `-1`s

```
mListSectionPos.add(mListItems.indexOf(current_item) - 1);
```

I guess, somehow you always check for the first `current_item`, which is the second element in `mListItems`. If you would check for the `beer_section` - as it does for `current_section` in the original code - the code would work as expected.

---

After looking into [`ArrayList.indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29), the most likely reason is your `PiwoSubclass.equals()` method compares always equal to the first non-section element, because it hasn't set a beer name or some similar condition.

So, fixing the `equals` method might work as well.

Comment: I suspect `equals` method as well.

Comment: First, I would check the values of `marka` and `marka_lowercase`. This is independent of Apache Commons Utils.

Comment: Okay, I found that (stupid!) error - in `equals` I checked marka_lowercase instead of `beerName` from `getBeerName()` which now works and `mListSectionPos` have proper values - so thanks for that one! It's my mistake of not checking things enough. I updated my question with another problem that resolves around that one - I'd be grateful for checking that as well :)

Comment: I'm glad this works now. :-) For me it is a bit late today, so maybe tomorrow. To get more eyes looking into this, I would rather not mix this here, but ask a separate question.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks again :)